# Concise way of chaining promise and passing value

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

What is the most concise way of writing this with Bluebird promises:

```
return someFunc().then(function(result) {
  return otherFunc(result).then(function(foo) {
    ...
  });
});
```

I see some util functions such as `result()` but not totally clear how/which I would use. Basically I need to call the 2nd function while passing the result of the first as the argument. Or is this the most concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.then(function(foo) { return foo; });` is redundant.

Given your example, this is all you need.

```
return someFunc().then(otherFunc);
```

Comment: That was just for example. I am interested in chaining while passing result as arguments

Comment: @Yashua Ok, then give us an example that actually shows what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it like this:

```
return someFunc()
.then(otherFunc)
.then(function(foo) {
    return foo; // assuming you do more here...
});
```

I hope this isn't your whole code, or the last function with a `return` would be useless and the whole would be equivalent to

```
return someFunc().then(otherFunc);
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work. I need to bind I think - is there a way to bind auto bind or do I need to do it for all calls?

Comment: There was no reason to bind in the example you showed.